# How do I run Ruby files whose path contains non-ASCII symbols?

Tags: ruby, windows

Running `d:\ruby\test.rb` is always successful.

Running the copy of this file path which is at `d:\программирование\test.rb` fails, apparently because it contains non-ASCII, Cyrillic in this case, symbols:

```
No such file or directory - D:\... (Errno::ENOENT)
```

What should I do to make it work?

I'm using Ruby 1.9 and Windows.

Comment: There wasn't a `:` between `D` and `\ ` in the error message when I converted it to code formatting -- is it missing in your error message as well? (Incidentally, I can't reproduce this with Ruby on Linux, so I agree that Windows is probably involved. Can you run `notepad d:\программирование\test.rb` to edit the file?)

Comment: There was a : between D and \. I mistyped, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your path like:

```
"d:\программирование\test.rb"
```

Then Ruby is treating the "\t" character as if is is escaped: It is converting `\t` into a tab before passing the filename to any routine. That character is illegal in a filename. Well, maybe not illegal, but a real pain to deal with and not what you expect.

Instead, use:

```
'd:\программирование\test.rb'
```

Or, better yet, let Ruby do the lifting and reverse your backslashes when you define the name. Ruby should do the right thing and convert them on the fly for you:

```
"d:/программирование/test.rb"
```

Comment: I tried running Ruby files by right-clicking them and by running bat-file in the same directory that looks like this: test.rb<br /> pause (instead of <br /> - newline)

Comment: Windows explorer may be creating it, but that doesn't mean the "\t" is valid in a programming language.